# Should I .gitignore before git commit or commit files before .gitignore?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I want to know if I should create the **.gitignore** file and add the files I do not want to be committed or if I should **commit** all files before creating my .gitignore file?

Comment: Add the files where? To git? Don't add files to git that you don't want tracked. Create the `.gitignore` first.

Comment: You must add your .gitignore before you commit any files you want to ignore :) Otherwise, it's a pain to fix it so they will stop being tracked (and you may have them in your git history - which is also bad if you wanted them to never make it into source control - also a pain to fix).

Comment: Are you asking if you should commit the files you want to ignore? But... but the entire point of ignoring files is to not accidentally commit them...

Comment: I think there may be an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/237313) here - what exactly are you trying to do with .gitignore where this question arises?

Answer (score 1):

You should create the `.gitignore` file before committing.  If you do it the other way around, then you might accidentally commit files you didn't want to include, like build products, generated documentation, or dependencies downloaded by your package manager.  Once those files are committed, adding them to `.gitignore` has no effect; that is, it doesn't ignore them.

If you create the `.gitignore` first, then Git will ignore those files when you run `git add`, and there's no risk of committing those files you don't want to include.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but the `.gitignore` file was `committed` when I ran git add. Is that okay or is there a way `not to commit` the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: You should generally commit the `.gitignore`, so that should be fine.